# Using checkboxes in an interactive report with primary key

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Having a small issue with checkboxes in an Apex report. I've added them to the interactive report fine, and everything works well when one box is selected and submitted for updating. However, I cannot select multiple boxes because I get an error about not having unique primary keys (My own constraint which I cannot break). The following is my current page process(Slightly edited for privacy) to update the database:

```
FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.count
LOOP
INSERT INTO table_name(user_photo_id, created_by, created_on, photo_id, user_id)
values(:P58_USER_PHOTO_ID, :F125_USER_ID,sysdate,:P58_PHOTOS,   apex_application.g_f01(i));
END LOOP;
```

The item that the primary key is derived from (:P58_USER_PHOTO_ID) get's the primary key from this code chunk:

```
declare 
function get_pk return varchar2 
is 
begin 
 for c1 in (select TABLE_USER_PHOTO_SEQ.nextval next_val
           from dual)
 loop
    return c1.next_val;
 end loop;
  end; 
   begin 
:P58_USER_PHOTO_ID := get_pk; 
 end;
```

Is there anything I can change in either of the two pieces of code so that regardless of how many items are selected, they each get their own unique primary key? Thanks for any help!

Comment: what are you trying to do here? For each selected user you insert a record into table name? Do you want to assign each inserted record a new photo id? Just clarify what you try to do here a bit more.

Comment: Users will choose a picture first, to be associate with each selected user from a table (Via checkbox). Each selected user should get a unique 'User Photo ID' for later referencing. This will be a new INSERT action, not an update action. Hopefully that's a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can ditch the second code chunk and just do this:

```
FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.count
LOOP
  INSERT INTO table_name(user_photo_id, created_by, created_on, photo_id, user_id)
  values(TABLE_USER_PHOTO_SEQ.nextval, :F125_USER_ID,sysdate,:P58_PHOTOS,   apex_application.g_f01(i));
END LOOP;
```

Comment: It doesn't like that, I get the following error:                 ORA-06550: line 5, column 11: PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist ORA-06550: line 4, column 4: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored                                                                Only thing I changed from your comment was to change the table name to match my own. I wouldn't think that alone would cause that error?

Comment: Much of why it goes wrong with what you try to achieve is probably because you have a page process which gets you a pk value and fills in P58_USER_PHOTO_ID. Afterwards, you do a loop over selected records, and for each record you use this item. Evidently you will run into the key constraint, since you use the same ID for each record. The solution is indeed to fetch a new ID for each inserted record, which is what Tony has done here. The sequence.nextval should work, but you could try to put it in a var first: v_id := table_user_photo_seq.nextval; and then use v_id in your insert?